# What's the "^" in RewriteRule Statements?

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I keep seeing the `^` character in `RewriteRule` statements in a context that doesn't fit with the usage specified [in this document about regular expressions](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~jbs/resources/perl/perl-basics/regular_expressions.html).

For example: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]`

What does it signify?

Comment: Useful: mod_rewrite Cheat Sheet by DaveChild at 
http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/

Comment: The usage in the linked document is the _same_ with mod_rewrite (the `RewriteRule` _pattern_). However, regex in Apache config files don't use delimiters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means "this matches the start of the string". So in your example the rule does the rewrite if there's

- the start of the string (`^`)
- any character (`.`)
- any number of the previous character (`*`)
- the end of the string (`$`)

In other words, this whole expression matches any string.

Comment: Ah, of course.  I always forget about the begin and end anchors.

Comment: .* means 0 or more characters, so a zero length string matches too.

Comment: Thanks @pritaeas for the update. I was doing it from memory.